# Subtracting one table from another in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains student IDs and their GPA.

```
_____________
| sID | GPA |
-------------
|  1  | 3.7 |
|  2  | 3.9 |
|  3  | 3.6 |
|  4  | 3.7 |
|  5  | 3.1 |
|  6  | 3.9 |
```

I wanted to create a table that gives me only the students who have the highest, or second highest GPAs. In other words, **I want this result:**

```
_____________
| sID | GPA |
-------------
|  2  | 3.9 |
|  6  | 3.9 |
|  1  | 3.7 |
|  4  | 3.7 |
```

To do so, I began by writing a query that gives me all the students who match the highest score:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gpaTable
WHERE gpa in (
      SELECT max(gpa) FROM gpaTable)
```

This gives me:

```
| sID | GPA |
-------------
|  2  | 3.9 |
|  6  | 3.9 |
```

To get the second highest as well, I want to **subtract** this result from the entire original table, and then repeat the query that finds the max again.

I assume it would look something like this, however, **I can't get it right.**

```
SELECT *
FROM gpaTable
WHERE gpa IN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM gpaTable
    WHERE gpa in (
          SELECT max(gpa) FROM gpaTable)
    )
 OR
    (SELECT *
     FROM gpaTable
     WHERE NOT EXISTS IN
           (SELECT * 
            FROM gpaTable
            WHERE gpa in (
            SELECT max(gpa) FROM gpaTable)
    )
```

In English, the query says (or should say) *Give me every row that appears in the table of maximum GPAs* **OR** *in the table of maximum GPAs of the lesser GPAs*

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select *
from gpaTable
where gpa in (
  select distinct gpa
  from gpaTable
  order by gpa desc
  limit 2
)
```

The idea is similar to your first solution, except `MAX` is replaced with ordering and a [`LIMIT 2`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html)

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cd6ce/1)

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to just select the top 2 entries in the subselect? You could, e.g., use [`LIMIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html):

```
SELECT * 
FROM gpaTable
WHERE gpa in (SELECT DISTINCT gpa FROM gpaTable ORDER BY gpa DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY gpa;
```

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to make it work how I wanted - and it does. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sid, gpa
FROM (
   select sid, 
          gpa, 
          dense_rank() over (order by gpa desc) as rnk
   from gpaTable
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by sid;
```